# Label and Input/Select alignment inside inline list in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'd like to have an inline-list with labels displaying on top of their corresponding inputs.

This fiddle shows a simple implementation that I'm using: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zy1uz0k3/9/)

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="Gender">Gender</label>
            <select id="Gender" name="Gender">
                <option value="1">Male</option>
                <option value="2">Female</option>
                <option value="3">N/A</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
input, select {
    display: block;
}
```

This works in well in all browsers except Firefox, and I am at a loss as to why. `float: left` isn't a great solution for me here because it will align the contents to the top of the `li`. In an ideal solution, the "Filter" button will be visually in line with the `input` and `select` elements to the left, as it does with the fiddle example above in IE and Chrome.

Comment: add jsfiddle code in question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using display: inline-block; for the input, select css as well?

```
input, select {
display: inline-block;
}
```

also, add display: block; to label in css.

example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/zy1uz0k3/10/

Answer (score 0):

Solution using FlexBox.

**[FlexBox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

```css
ul {
  list-style: outside none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
}
li.submit {
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
li.submit [type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="Gender">Gender</label>
      <select id="Gender" name="Gender">
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
        <option value="3">N/A</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <li class="submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```